# Wanting to list all Post types under a common category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, theme-twenty-twelve

A client has "posts" plus four custom post types on their site. He requested a way to call up a category that would be common to the CPTs and list them all. So if there is a common category of "budget", then it would display excerpts of all posts with the category of "budget" regardless of what post or CPT it is.

I found a few related topics here to help me write up a template to use on pages devoted to the few categories they want to use with this. It's on a child theme based on TwentyTwelve. The result I'm getting is the white screen of death. I've got through debugging several times and the error I get is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/acs10047/public_html/wp-content/themes/moneysmartfamily/page-category-budgeting.php on line 53

But that's a blank line. So I don't know what's wrong here. I'm trying.

Since I'm piecing together different topics, I must be missing out on some understanding how they work together. Could someone advise me on what I'm doing here?

Here is the template code:

```
<?php
```

/**
 * Template Name: Category - Budgeting
 *
 *
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header();

```
    $args = array('post_type' => array('post','media-appearance','members-archive','money-saving-tips','review'),
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
);

    $this_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php while ( $this_query->have_posts()) : $this_query->the_post(); {?>

        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() && ($cat == 'budget') ): ?>
    <div class="tip-excerpt">                                     
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>        

                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php  // done the foreach statement ?>


    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: One solution would be to remove the CPTs. Make all of them Posts, and then convert their `single-cpt-1.php` files into `tpl-type-1.php` files that support the Post post type. That way their former CPTs will still be able to use different templates to get whatever functionality they want, but they will all natively have access to Categories and natively be listed in each category archive.

Comment: True, but my client does not want to lose the ability to have those blog listings for each CPT.